# DHCPv4 connection considered critical, ignoring request to reconfigure it

Tags: networking, systemd

I am seeing these log on a server but don't know what does it mean?

```
systemd-networkd[3423]: eth1: Link DOWN
systemd-networkd[3423]: eth1: Lost carrier
systemd-networkd[3423]: eth1: DHCPv4 connection considered critical, ignoring request to reconfigure it.
```

Does it mean someone/something is requested to change the eth1 config but systemd reject to accept it?

Answer (score 0):

The starting point is that the network connection failed - there could be many reasons for this including a hardware problem. This would normally lead systemd-networkd to release the ip address internally, but because you have it marked as 'critical' (e.g. if you use netplan, you have 'critical: true' in your `/etc/netplan/config.yaml`), it did not do so, it held on to the ip address internally even though there was no external connection.

This is probably the behaviour you want if network connection failures are likely to be very brief and/or you never want that ip address to change.